# How to increment an object property, later i check it and disable itself if date/year mismatches

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I'm writing some code,to get the year, then check it  during my load screen.  If it's not 2017,I want the game object to destroy itself.. it will be a version of the game I give to friends for testing..So next year when I'm hopefully selling the game, it wont work for these test builds.  Here's my code,somethings wrong, I usually don't code in python.  I thought this would work. The object has an int property called dateok. It has another sensor to check dateok and destroy itself if the value is 1;

```
import datetime   
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

def main():

    if day.year!=2017:

        owner = cont.owner
        dateok = cont.actuators['dateok']
        value = value.get(dateok.propname) +1
        dateok.value = str(value)
        cont.activate(dateok)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check the current date:

```
from datetime import datetime

if datetime.now().year>2017:
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

import bge

cont = bge.logic.getcurrentController()

if datetime.datetime.now() > datetime.datetime(2018,1,1,1):

    ownwer = cont.owner
    owner["property"] +=1
```

I figured it out..thanks anyways guys